# javascript библиотека view + шаблонизатор + virtual dom?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны

Ищу js маленький(не больше 30 kb), фреймворк или набор js файлов. 
Чтобы можно было создать компонент(с html кодом или через шаблонизатор), вставлять один компонент в другой, передавать данные json в шаблонизатор, подключать какие нибудь функции валидации(сторонние например) к нему, вызывать пользовательские функции из шаблонизатора, быстро находить элементы-компоненты dom по id. Вешал бы события на virtual dom, а не на сам dom.
Но чтобы он работал быстро, не тормозил, нормально работал в старых браузерах(не обязательно поддерживать все фичи, но и не так что только самые современные поддерживаются).

Какие подобные существуют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пробовал, но вот [Mithril](http://mithril.js.org/) (7k gzipped)

Ещё [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom), [ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/) и [mercury](https://github.com/Raynos/mercury).